# Add recevied data to existing receive buffer in MPI_SendRecv

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

I am trying to send data(forces) across 2 processes, using `MPI_SendRecv`. Usually the data will be over written in the received  buffer, I do not want to overwrite the data in the received buffer instead I want to add the data it received.

I can do the following. Store the data in the previous time step to a different array and then add it after receiving. But I have huge number of nodes and I do not want to have memory allocated for its storage every time step. (or overwrite the same)

My question is there a way to add the received data directly to the buffer and store it in the received memory using MPI?

Any help in this direction would be really thankful.

I am sure collective communication calls (MPI Reduce)cannot be worked out here. Are there any other commands that can do this?

Comment: Do you mean add like sum, or add like append?

Comment: i think the reference to MPI_Reduce indicates that he is referring to numerical addition rather than buffer.push_back.

Answer (score 3):

In short: no, but you should be able to do this.

In long: Your suggestion makes a great deal of sense and the MPI Forum is currently considering new features that would enable essentially what you want.

It is incorrect to suggest that the data must be received before it can be accumulated.  MPI_Accumulate does a remote accumulation in a one-sided fashion.  You want MPI_Sendrecv_accumulate rather than MPI_Sendrecv_replace.  This makes perfect sense and an implementation can internally do much better than you can because it can buffer on a per-packet basis, for example.

For suszterpatt, MPI internally buffers in the eager protocol and in the rendezvous protocol can setup a pipeline to minimize buffering.

The implementation of MPI_Recv_accumulate (for simplicity, as the MPI_Send part need not be considered) looks like this:

```
int MPI_Recv(void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, int source, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status)
{
 if (eager)
  MPI_Reduce_local(_eager_buffer, buf, count, datatype, op);
 else /* rendezvous */
 {
   malloc _buffer
   while (mycount<count)
   {
     receive part of the incoming data into _buffer
     reduce_local from _buffer into buf
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.

In long: your suggestion doesn't really make sense. The machine can't perform any operations on your received value without first putting it into local memory somewhere. You'll need a buffer to receive the newest value, and a separate sum that you will increment by the buffer's content after every receive.

Comment: yes, i did the same , first i stored the values in the memory to a temp array and then do the communication and then add the received values to the buffer, but then i have to do independently after each send/recv command and in each directions( 3 * 2 for both pos and neg directions), little bit of extra code though it is same ...thanks very much for the response .